# scikitlearn adapt bigram to svm

Tags: python, nltk, svm

I have problem. here's my code.
http://colorscripter.com/s/9vc2ryj

And I mistaked. evaluate_classifier(bigram_word_feats) is what I want.

I'm trying to text mining by SVM.
The feature vectors are bigram model.
But I got a problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/LG/Desktop/untitled1/TEST.py", line 184, in <module>
evaluate_classifier(bigram_word_feats)
File "C:/Users/LG/Desktop/untitled1/TEST.py", line 90, in evaluate_classifier
classifier.train(trainfeats)
File "C:\Users\LG\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\scikitlearn.py", line 115, in train
X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
File "C:\Users\LG\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 226, in fit_transform
return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
File "C:\Users\LG\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 190, in _transform
feature_names.sort()
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < str()
```

Why this happen and how can I solve?
and what's the process of nltk classifier?
give it to my feature word and period? Then it just generate svm model?

Oh and I'm using python 3. Do I need to use python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New answer:

I think the problem is that `nltk` expects a dict indexed by strings instead of tuples. Can you try to replace the `return` statement from:

```
return dict([(ngram, True) for ngram in itertools.chain(words, bigrams)])
```

to the following:

```
return dict([('|'.join (ngram), True) for ngram in itertools.chain(words, bigrams)])
```

### Old answer:

<del>`train` methods of Scikit-learn predictors expect two inputs: features and targets. Something like the following (not tested):</del>

```
negfeats = [featx(f) for f in word_split(negdata)]
posfeats = [featx(f) for f in word_split(posdata)]
...
trainlabels = [-1,] * negcutoff + [+1,] * poscutoff
classifier.train(trainfeats, trainlabels)
```

<del>In defining `trainlabels`, I followed your style of using arithmetic operators on lists but I wouldn't do it in my code as it makes it less readable.</del>

Comment: Thanks. But I don't get it. It may sound like weird or strange, but it's just depends on my english conversation skill So plz never mind. So what does the train label provide? It seems that my SVM works fine indeed without the label. Does my code automatically input some label?

Comment: And I just tested it with bag-of-words model, but failed: TypeError: train() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

Comment: Sorry. I though you were using scikit-learn directly while instead you use nltk, which in turn uses scikit-learn. I think the problem is that nltk expects a dict indexed by strings instead of tuples. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. There's no issue like my case anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't work.. :( Oh and I wanna ask you something. You said you though that I'm using scikit-learn directly, but I didn't. but which one is faster? It's just my test and I'll use this huge data set. really huge.

Comment: Yes It work. Sorry... mistake while copy & paste I guess.
thank you sooo much!! But how did you do this? Why does it work? can you explain me or give me any reference for me please?

Comment: The `train`  method's documentation states:
           " where each 'featureset' is a dict mapping strings to either
            numbers, booleans or strings  ". Your attempt used tuples made of the words of each bigram. A simple way to obtain a string from a tuple  is to concatenate the words into a string,  e.g. `("people","like")` into "people|like".

Comment: Thank you. um.. I'm really sorry but I got another issue... the result(F-score/ accuracy/recall/precision) of both 2-gram and bag of words feature selection approach are exactly same. I guess `train` just recognize both parameter as same.

Comment: Solving one, other one comes out... What the... :(

Comment: Oh and this is the reference of [it](http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/24/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-stopwords-collocations/)